# Can the performance of this canvas drawImage() test be improved?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas

I have a quite simple loop that draws an 8px by 8px image many times in a canvas in a tiling fashion. Currently it's drawing 7500 images each loop.

[See the jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/eLgthrue/)

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/3dzaMlv.png';

var W = 8;
var H = 8;
var R = 800/W;
var C = 600/H

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var fps = document.getElementById('fps');
var timePrev = new Date().getTime();
var fpsInterval = 30;
var i = 0;

window.setInterval(function() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);

    for (var r=0 ; r<R ; r++) {
        for (var c=0 ; c<C ; c++) {
            ctx.drawImage(img, r*W, c*H);
        }
    }

    // fps
    if (i % fpsInterval == 0) {
        var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
        var spf = (timeNow - timePrev) / fpsInterval / 1000;
        fps.innerHTML = (1/spf).toFixed(2);
        timePrev = timeNow;
    }
    i++;

}, 1000/60);
```

On my I7-2700K (3.5GHz) processor and ATI Radeon HD7970, I am getting the following framerates:

- Chrome 36.0.1985.143 m  :  **~40 FPS**
- Firefox 30.0            :  **~55 FPS**
- IE 11.0.9600.17239      :  **~35 FPS**

Is there any way to improve FPS performance here, assuming I do actually need to draw this many tiles on each update?

EDIT: To clarify, I'm requiring that they be drawn as individual tiles on each update. So, rendering them all to an off-screen canvas wouldn't work. I am essentially disappointed in the number of drawImage() calls that seems to perform well.

Comment: you should know you are off topic to SO go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks wintermute. [I cross-posted there.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61825/can-the-performance-of-this-canvas-drawimage-test-be-improved)

Comment: Actually, drawing to an off-screen canvas is exactly what I'd do. Draw each of the tiles to the off-screen one, then blast the entire canvas to the visible canvas. On this machine (i7-3537U - intel hd4000), performance went from ~22fps to ~25fps. Not a quantum change, but essentially a 10%+ increase for the cost of 3 extra lines of code. Also, you wont need the `clearRect` call unless your tiles have transparent areas. Line1. clone the existing canvas element. Line2. get the ctx of the clone, (change code to draw tiles to the copy), Line 4. draw image from copy to onscreen canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/. Your code may be rewritten like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fv99o6jc/

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here's one way to use far fewer drawImage's:

```
// make a template column
for(var y=0;y<ch;y+=ih){
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,y);
}

// flood-fill with the template column
for(var x=iw;x<cw;x+=iw){
    ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0,iw,ch,x,0,iw,ch);
}
```

A Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="http://i.imgur.com/3dzaMlv.png";
function start(){

  var iw=img.width;
  var ih=img.height;

  // make a template column
  for(var y=0;y<ch;y+=ih){
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,y);
  }

  // flood-fill with the template column
  for(var x=iw;x<cw;x+=iw){
    ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0,iw,ch,x,0,iw,ch);
  }

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```